# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference

Tags: java

I keep getting this error and i'm not sure why. I've tried googling it but no luck there.

> 04-21 15:43:24.822    2461-2461/com.example.s.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>       04-21 15:43:24.823    2461-2461/com.example.s.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.s.myapplication, PID: 2461
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.s.myapplication/com.example.s.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3539)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
>                   at com.example.s.myapplication.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:46)
>                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6139)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3535)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>       a

This is my main activity. What the application is meant to do is:

1. Take a photo
2. Save the photo in a tmp location
3. load the photo into a imageview

.

```
package com.example.s.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private ImageView imageView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        openCamera();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openCamera() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image.jpg");
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }



    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //Check that request code matches ours:
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            //Get our saved file into a bitmap object:
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image.jpg");
            Bitmap image = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 1000, 700);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) { 

        //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        }
        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }

        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }

    public void capture_btn(View v) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image.jpg");
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: you never initialize imageView to anything in your code, so it's null.

Comment: imageView.setImageBitmap(image);???

Comment: That's calling a method on an object instance. Since nowhere in your code is see imageView=<something>, imageView is null, and you can't call anything on it.

Comment: Thank you, i've added 'imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);'

Answer (score 6):

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

I wrote wrong the id of my imageView. It supposed to be imageView2

imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

Answer (score 0):

if above solutions did not work for you check

oncreate  method again it should be like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                                             }
```