# Upload Image in profile

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask

I have to upload my image to the application in the profile fragment so I have used two buttons. One to select from the gallery and one to upload it. When I executed my code I could open the gallery to select an image but as soon as i click the button my application closes.
This is the `error` i am getting:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.hp.truckloaderadmin, PID: 32605
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:5746
>   flg=0x1 VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null,
>   mFlags=0x00000000)} }} to activity
>   {com.example.hp.truckloaderadmin/com.example.hp.truckloaderadmin.common.common.FragProfile}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5008)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5051)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7410)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                        at
>   com.example.hp.truckloaderadmin.common.common.FragProfile.onActivityResult(FragProfile.java:103)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7165)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5004)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5051) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229) 
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7410) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

**And this is my code for it:**

```
public class FragProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
Bitmap bitmap;
boolean check = true;
FloatingActionButton imgUp;
FloatingActionButton imgSel;
Button update;
EditText imageName;
ImageView image;
ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
String ImageName = "image_name" ;
String GetImageNameEditText;
String ImagePath = "image_path" ;
String ServerUploadPath ="http://192.168.43.38/internship_project/android_web_services/image.php";

@Nullable
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frag_profile);
    imgSel=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabSelect);
    imageName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextImageName);
    imgUp=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabUpload);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    imgUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetImageNameEditText = imageName.getText().toString();
            ImageUploadToServerFunction();

        }
    });
    imgSel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 1);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {

    super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);

    if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = I.getData();

        try {

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void ImageUploadToServerFunction(){

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStreamObject ;

    byteArrayOutputStreamObject = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStreamObject);

    byte[] byteArrayVar = byteArrayOutputStreamObject.toByteArray();

    final String ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayVar, Base64.DEFAULT);

    class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FragProfile.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

            super.onPostExecute(string1);

            // Dismiss the progress dialog after done uploading.
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            // Printing uploading success message coming from server on android app.
            Toast.makeText(FragProfile.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Setting image as transparent after done uploading.
            image.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

            HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();

            HashMapParams.put(ImagePath, ConvertImage);

            String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest(ServerUploadPath, HashMapParams);

            return FinalData;
        }
    }
    AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();

    AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
}

public class ImageProcessClass{

    public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnectionObject ;
            OutputStream OutPutStream;
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriterObject ;
            BufferedReader bufferedReaderObject ;
            int RC ;

            url = new URL(requestURL);

            httpURLConnectionObject = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnectionObject.setReadTimeout(19000);

            httpURLConnectionObject.setConnectTimeout(19000);

            httpURLConnectionObject.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnectionObject.setDoInput(true);

            httpURLConnectionObject.setDoOutput(true);

            OutPutStream = httpURLConnectionObject.getOutputStream();

            bufferedWriterObject = new BufferedWriter(

                    new OutputStreamWriter(OutPutStream, "UTF-8"));

            bufferedWriterObject.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));

            bufferedWriterObject.flush();

            bufferedWriterObject.close();

            OutPutStream.close();

            RC = httpURLConnectionObject.getResponseCode();

            if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                bufferedReaderObject = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnectionObject.getInputStream()));

                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String RC2;

                while ((RC2 = bufferedReaderObject.readLine()) != null){

                    stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        StringBuilder stringBuilderObject;

        stringBuilderObject = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {

            if (check)

                check = false;
            else
                stringBuilderObject.append("&");

            stringBuilderObject.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

            stringBuilderObject.append("=");

            stringBuilderObject.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return stringBuilderObject.toString();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Its clearly a NPE . Your imageview is null . Check R.id.image exists in layout or not . Also you created an activity with name as fragment ?? Follow the naming conventions to make things easy to understand .

Comment: So do I need a default image to replace it?

Comment: I made it as fragment first but I couldn't get the answer for the fragments one so i changed it to activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777098/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-widget-imageview-setimagebitmapa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)